# How to solve Import error sql-tools in python

Tags: python

I tried to use `sqlite` import `sql-tools` package in python but I got an error in executing. How can I solve that?

Comment: Show the code, and the error you get. It could be any number of things and there isn't enough information in your post to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `sqlite` as a sub package of `sql-tools`

```py
from sql_tools import sqlite

sqlite.connect(yourDb)
sqlite.execute("your query")
sqlite.disconnect()
```